# Lucene - search works, but gives "UnsupportedOperationException" when deployed to Tomcat. Why?

Tags: java, exception, lucene, tomcat6

The code under works when I run it as a java application locally, but "reader.directory()" gives "UnsupportedOperationException: This reader does not support this method." Someone have an idea why?

```
public ExternalSearch() {
  System.out.println("Initialize Lucene-Search");
  analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_20);

  File file = new File("index");

try {
   Directory dir = FSDirectory.open(file);
   reader = IntexReader.open(dir, true);
} catch (IOException e) {
   System.out.println("ERROR: Could not read index -> " + e.getMessage());
   e.printStackTrace();
}
this.index = reader.directory();
```

}

Comment: Are you running the same versions of Tomcat locally and remotely?

Comment: Possibly a different version of Lucene is used locally and on Tomcat?

Comment: is *dir* valid or null? From the javadocs, * throws an UnsupportedOperationException if no directory* http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_1/api/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexReader.html#directory()

Comment: @JoseK Thanks, thats it! For some reason it interpreted my relative path "index" as "D:\index" ...